# Python SKIP element in JSON

Tags: python, json

I would like to get an element from the JSON tree

```
dataMod = data['products'][VARIABLE]['bla']['bla']
```

but I faced an issue when one of the element in this tree have VARIABLE inside, it is any clean way of skipping it? like:

```
dataMod = data['products'][*]['bla']['bla']
```

ANSWER:

```
for p in data['products']:
     skipPLU = data['products'][p]
     productPLU = skipPLU['bla']['bla']
```

Comment: Rather broad, but what about considering `data['products']` and then iterating on its elements and consistently process `x['blah']['blah']`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta So python does not have any wrappers or other packages and other ways not make it cleaner?

Comment: Terminology nitpick: strictly speaking, this doesn't have anything to do with json. There is no "json tree" class in the standard Python libraries, not even in the `json` module. Most likely `data` is an ordinary dictionary, containing other ordinary dictionaries. But that's not to say that your question is invalid; it's still an interesting problem.

Comment: `jq` is a programming language that can help you parse JSON better. But if you're looking to do it in a more Pythonic way so to speak, you can check out this library I'm currently working on (shameless plug). I originally built this for a very specific use case but I'm planning on scaling it to other use cases. Feel free to open up an issue if this doesn't fit your needs!
https://github.com/prithajnath/kalamari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
head = data['products']

for skip in head :
    for data in head[skip]:
        print(head[skip][data]['bla']['bla'])
```

This will get all data under data['products'][VARIABLE]

Comment: Kind of , but have - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I don't know what's in your json. Maybe you can print skip/data in the first line of for loop